# How can I use Flickity JS for two containers with same click events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickity

I have simple div in which I have two containers with images and some text:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="img-container">
        <div class="slide-img">
            <img src="img/bg1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <img src="img/bg1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-container">
        <div class="slide-text">
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-text">
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And now I want to target containers with Flickity js,
So if I do this:

```
$('.img-container').flickity({
    cellAlign: 'left',
    contain: true
});
$('.text-container').flickity({
    cellAlign: 'left',
    contain: true
});
```

I will get two sliders, but I want one slider with one pair of navigation arrows and one page dots and same events.
So when I click or drag navigation both containers should animate.
What should I do?
Can you help me, please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the text and image into one slide in one flickity carousel.

Comment: I can't, because next I will pass some animation and etc. So if all will be in one container, I will not get animation I want. @evolutionxbox

Comment: Then you’re in for a complicated journey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `asNavFor` option to trigger the `img-container` slider

```js
$('.img-container').flickity();
// 2nd carousel, navigation

$('.text-container').flickity({
  asNavFor: '.img-container',
  contain: true,
  pageDots: false,
  prevNextButtons: false
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  background: #FAFAFA;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.slide-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.text-container .slide-text {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
}

.slide-text.is-nav-selected {
  background: #ED2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/2.2.1/flickity.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/2.2.1/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img-container carousel">
    <div class="slide-img">
      <img src="img/bg1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide-img">
      <img src="img/bg1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-container carousel">
    <div class="slide-text">
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-text">
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```